# Map Function with Table on each row

Tags: list-manipulation

I need help as I am new to Mathematica. I have a table with some nominal bond values:

```
 {
 {, Nominal, Maturity, Coupon },
 {Bond 1, 200, 1, 0.05},
 {Bond 2, 110, 15, 0.1},
 {Bond 3, 195, 7, 0.05},
 {Bond 4, 100, 25, 0.025},
 {Bond 5, 100, 10, 0.03}
}
```

and I want to calculate the Value of the bond with the following function but I could not map it right so that the values fit. Could someone help me ?

Here is the function for the valuation of the bond. If I paste each value by hand it works fine but I have to match it with the table with the Map function.

```
mwbond2[Nominal_, Maturity_, Coupon_, int0_] := Module[
  {n = Nominal, m = Maturity, c = Coupon, int = int0},
  MW = Sum[n*c /(1+int)^i, {i, 1, m, 1}] + n/(1 + int)^m; Print[MW]]
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: `Dataset` might be a good fit for storing and processing this data.

Answer (score 2):

Using your data

```
list = {{, Nominal, Maturity, Coupon}, {Bond 1, 200, 1., 
    0.05}, {Bond 2, 110., 15., 0.1}, {Bond 3, 195., 7., 
    0.05}, {Bond 4, 100., 25., 0.025}, {Bond 5, 100., 10., 0.03}};
```

and a slightly modified version of your function

```
mwbond2[Nominal_, Maturity_, Coupon_, int0_] := 
 Module[{n = Nominal, m = Maturity, c = Coupon, int = int0}, 
  Sum[n*c/(1 + int)^i, {i, 1, m, 1}] + n/(1 + int)^m]
```

Note that `Module` evaluates to the `Sum` given at the end.  Assigning the value to a variable is unnecessary here and I get it to return a value rather than printing it.

We don't use the row or column labels, so drop these

```
list1 = Drop[#, 1] & /@ Drop[list, 1]
(* {{200, 1., 0.05}, {110., 15., 0.1}, {195., 7., 0.05}, {100., 
  25., 0.025}, {100., 10., 0.03}} *)
```

We do want an interest rate (which I assume you omitted inadvertently).  I use rates of 1%, 2%, ..., 5% for the 5 cases.  I add the rates into the table

```
list2 = MapThread[Append, {list1, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}/100}]
(* {{200, 1., 0.05, 1/100}, {110., 15., 0.1, 1/50}, {195., 7., 
  0.05, 3/100}, {100., 25., 0.025, 1/25}, {100., 10., 0.03, 1/20}} *)
```

I now apply the function to each row of the table

```
mwbond2 @@@ list2
(* {207.921, 223.074, 219.298, 76.5669, 84.5565} *)
```